# What happens when when casting an int to unsigned int in C?

Tags: c

I have:

```
int i = -INT32_MIN
unsigned int ui = (unsigned int)i
```

What will happen when I cast the int to an unsigned int?

- What are the rules for casting?
- Is casting safe?
- Will casting always produce a predictable value?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Try it.  Check the C spec.  Depends on what you mean by _safe_.  Yes.

Comment: @Avi I disagree with your edit: If question is about Objective-C, don't change it to C, even if the answer were the same. Please rollback.

Comment: `int i = -INT32_MIN;` is likely to be undefined behaviour so the rest of the code is moot